# In the direction of light rays phase of the particle decrease

Tags: optics, waves

Recently I had been going through wave optics. And our teacher taught that the phase of particle decreases along the direction of light rays. Please someone explain is that true and how. And if not then please tell how does the phase vary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you or your teacher call "the phase of particle" what "particles" are you taking about?

Comment: In case wave equation y= Asin(kx-wt+phi) then considering a mechanical waves the particles are doing shm with frequency w. The phase which I was talking about is the term inside the sin function.